# How to flash a phone or a tablet with Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview from Windows

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Following the [Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview announcement](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2013/02/releasing-the-ubuntu-touch-developer-preview-and-sdk-alpha/), [installation instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) were published to easily install it on supported devices.

These instructions require an Ubuntu machine as a host device to run the flashing tools. How can developers and testers running other platforms, such as Windows, flash their test tablets or phones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CODE - DEVICE

maguro - Galaxy Nexus

mako - Nexus 4

grouper - Nexus 7

manta - Nexus 10

Installing Ubuntu touch through any OS is pretty simple and straight forward.

On Windows:

1. Unlock your device bootloader by following these instructions: http://www.android.gs/how-to-unlock-galaxy-nexus-bootloader/
2. Flash clockworkmod recovery on the device while staying in the bootloader mode. You can get device specific recovery from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/quantal/mwc-demo/). For example recovery file for Nexus 4 is quantal-preinstalled-recovery-armel+mako.img so the command to flash recovery on that device is

   ```
   fastboot flash recovery quantal-preinstalled-recovery-armel+mako.img
   ```

   You will have to make sure that in cmd you are in the location where the recovery file exisits.
3. Now start up the device and paste the two zips on the root directory of the device. For Nexus 4:

   - quantal-preinstalled-armel+mako.zip
   - quantal-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip (this is the unversal file for all devices)
4. Again power off the phone and start the bootloader mode, there select "Recovery" and press power button to start the recovery mode.
5. First select 'install zip from sdcard' and press the power button then 'chose zip from sdcard' there first flash quantal-preinstalled-armel+mako.zip and then quantal-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip
6. Reboot